# Microsoft.OData.Client: is there a way to turn on the URI Literal suffixes for numeric types?

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

There was a change "3.2.10 Pruned: URI Literal suffixes for numeric types" in OData v4 specification. Now OData.Client for OData v4 sends double literals without these sfuffixes, but we need them for our proejct to work correctly. I can't find a legal way to turn back this OData v3 behaviour, except brancing OData.Client. Does anybody know a way to change this behaviour using the generated T4 client proxies or something?

Answer (score 0):

It can't fallback to old numeric format (with suffix) . You may consider hooking up DataServiceContext's SendingRequest2 event,  modify the request URL to meet the server side's expectation.

However, the server side should have numeric value's type information (either in model or in CLR types) just like client has for building the request, so theoretically, suffix is unnecessary.